# Subset rows where all other columns meet a condition R

Tags: r

Hello I ve been trying for 2 days to solve this issue but i have not been able to, I would really appreciate the help, I have the following data frame :

[image]

I have 48 columns , one of them is called orthogroups and the other 47 are organisms names, in the Orthogroup column The rows are filled with the orthogroup names while bellow the organism name columns there are numbers that represent the number of copies of the orthogroups from the orthogroup column.

I ve been trying to make a subset where I substract orthogroup rows where all values from the adjacent columns are either 0 or one
For example OG00001 = 1, 0 , 1 ,0 ,1 etc.
I tried using this command

```
newdf <- subset(Orthogroups.GeneCount, Orthogroups.GeneCount[1:48,] == 1)
```

Or maybe if there is no `Orthogroup` where the condition is meet then get those rows where the condition is meet in a x number of columns like in at least 32 columns out of 48 the condition is meet and only shows those 32 orthogroups where is meet, I used to have a command for this but I lost it. Thanks a lot for the help, I tried with `dplyr` filter but `%>%` does not work.

Comment: Provide example data as text.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (not tested):

```
Orthogroups.GeneCount[
  rowSums(Orthogroups.GeneCount[, -1] == 0 |
            Orthogroups.GeneCount[, -1] == 1) == ncol(Orthogroups.GeneCount) - 1, ]
```